# How to use typeclass inheritance?

Tags: scala

```
trait Functor[F[_]]:
  extension[A] (fa: F[A])
    def map[B](f: A => B): F[B]

trait Applicative[F[_]: Functor]:
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]

  extension[A, B] (fab: F[A => B])
    def ap(fa: F[A]): F[B]

object Applicative:
  def pure[A, F[_]](a: A)(using ap: Applicative[F]): F[A] = ap.pure(a)

@targetName("apFirst")
def <*[A, B, F[_]: Applicative](fa: F[A], fb: F[B]): F[A] = fa.map(a => (_: B) => a).ap(fb)
```

Error: value map is not a member of type F in <*.

I get error in the last function. If I add Functor constraint it works, but shouldn't it work without that since I constrained it in the Applicative definition? What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type class inheritance is a normal inheritance:

```
trait Functor[F[_]]:
  extension[A] (fa: F[A])
    def map[B](f: A => B): F[B]

trait Applicative[F[_]] extends Functor[F]:
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]

  extension[A, B] (fab: F[A => B])
    def ap(fa: F[A]): F[B]
  
  extension[A] (fa: F[A])
    override def map[B](f: A => B): F[B] = pure(f).ap(fa)
```

Be cautious when you use it though, as having 2 type classes having the same parent will result in conflicting instances:

```
trait TypeClass1[A]
  def method: A
object TypeClass1:
  def method[A: TypeClass1]: A = summon[TypeClass1[A]].method

trait TypeClass2[A] extends TypeClass1[A]:
  def method2: A
  override def method: A = method2

trait TypeClass3[A] extends TypeClass1[A]:
  def method3: A
  override def method: A = method3

def usage[A: TypeClass2: TypeClass3] =
  TypeClass1.method[A] // ambiguous implicit
```

This issue can be seen in some Cats Effect 2 type class hierarchy.

When you define things like this:

```
trait Functor[F[_]]:
  extension[A] (fa: F[A])
    def map[B](f: A => B): F[B]

trait Applicative[F[_]: Functor]:
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]

  extension[A, B] (fab: F[A => B])
    def ap(fa: F[A]): F[B]
```

then *the inside* of `Applicative[F]` sees that `F` is a `Functor` and has access to `.map`... but `F : Functor` is a constraint, not a proper type bound. It desugars to `(using Functor[F])` which is merely an argument to a constructor (or other method), not something which `extends` interface nor encodes in its type any information about inheritance. As far as the outside of `Applicative` is concerned in such code there is no relationship between `Functor[F]` and `Applicative[F]`.

Additionally, the relation would be backward - `Functor`'s `map` can be implemented with `pure` and `ap`, not otherwise, and `F` being a `Applicative` proves that `F` is a `Functor`, so it could kinda work with something like:

```
trait Functor[F[_]]:
  extension[A] (fa: F[A])
    def map[B](f: A => B): F[B]
object Functor:
  given fromApplicative[F[_]: Applicative]: Functor[F] with
    extension[A] (fa: F[A])
      override def map[B](f: A => B): F[B] =
        summon[Applicative[F]].pure(f).ap(fa)

trait Applicative[F[_]:
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]

  extension[A, B] (fab: F[A => B])
    def ap(fa: F[A]): F[B]
```

Then there would still be no relationship between Applicative and Functor types, but every time there would be `given Appilcative[F]` a `given Functor[F]` could be constructed. However, this encoding would be harder to debug if you missed something, so just extending traits is both easier, safer and potentially less taxing on GC (only 1 instance passed down, rather than spawning a lot of them on demand).